# kendo grid date filter not working with before and after

Tags: sorting, date, filter, kendo-ui, grid

I'm using a kendo grid to display the data. When I filter on the date field specifying a date value (equals) then it works fine. But when I use the before or after conditions in the filter, it filters the data incorrectly.

Also sorting on the date field does not sort it properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. FYI: I used the moment.js to format the data in dd/mm/yyyy format.

Here is the code snippet with the data:

```
$("#testgrid").kendoGrid({
    change:onChange,
    dataSource: {
        data: [
            {"No":"27691","ClientName":"ABC","ExpiryDate":"2015-03-14T00:00:00Z"},
            {"No":"27691","Name":"DEF","ExpiryDate":"2016-03-22T00:00:00Z"},
            {"No":"27691","Name":"ABC","ExpiryDate":"2015-02-28T00:00:00Z"},
            {"No":"27691","Name":"ABC","ExpiryDate":"2011-07-03T00:00:00Z"},
            {"No":"27691","Name":"ABC","ExpiryDate":"2015-07-31T00:00:00Z"},
            {"No":"27691","Name":"ABC","ExpiryDate":null},
            {"No":"27691","Name":"ABC","ExpiryDate":"2012-04-30T00:00:00Z"}
        ],
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    No: { type: "string" },
                    ExpiryDate: {
                        type: "date",
                        parse: function(inputdate) {
                            var dtval = moment(inputdate).format('DD/MM/YYYY');

                            if (dtval == "Invalid date")
                                return "";
                            else  return dtval;}
                        },
                        Name: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 20
        },
        height: 550,
        selectable: "single row",
        allowCopy: true,
        resizable: true,
        groupable: true,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: {
            mode: 'row',
            extra: false,
            operators: {
                string: {
                    startswith: "Starts with",
                    eq: "Is equal to",
                    neq: "Is not equal to"
                }
            }
        },
        pageable: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "No", title: "Number", filterable: { cell: { showOperators: true, operator: "contains" } } , width: 150 },
                    { field: "Name", title: "Name",  filterable: { cell: { showOperators: true} }, width: 150 },                         
                    { field: "ExpiryDate", title: "Expiry Date",
                      format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",   filterable: {
                                cell: {
                                    template: function (args) {
                                    args.element.kendoDatePicker({
                                    format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
                                        });
                                    }
                                }}
                    , width: 150 }
                   ]
                });`
```

Comment: At this time, this is probably no longer an issue for you. In the future, it will help if you specify what is expected. For example, when you say the sorting is not working, it would have helped if you specified what the sort order *should* be and what it *actually* is.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, I've been struggling with an issue related to the filter field its self; I couldn't change the format of the date...

Your section of code for the "ExpiryDate" field helped solve my problem!

> { filterable: { cell: { template: function (args) { args.element.kendoDatePicker({ format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" }); } 
>   }}

Thought it might be useful to highlight this for others.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `parse` setting in the schema probably solves the sorting problem. On the filtering, perhaps the "problem" is that your dates are in UTC, but Kendo displays them in your browser's local time, and you need to deal with time.

I am in US Central Daylight Time (CDT), so `2015-03-14T00:00:00Z` shows as `13/03/2015` in the  grid. If I use an "equals" filter with `13/03/2015` then I get no results in the grid. Same thing - no result - with `14/03/2015`. If I change the datepicker template format to `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` and filter by equals `13/03/2015 19:00:00` then I get that entry, as expected.

Thus in order to use "equals" you must have (a) the time component and (b) remember the conversion of local to UTC.

Demo in [Kendo Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/AkIRI)